# Downloadable images using react

Tags: react-native

In my react website project, I want to make the picture downloadable by clicking the button, but the question is the pictures directory locally (example: /src/images.png). If I uploaded the website publicly by using cpanel, is the pictures can be downloaded by user although make it locally and how to make it publicly?

I expected that the picture can be downloaded by everyone without depends on local files